Reference a custom object property using a variable for property name
Let's say you have %tSheetObject['results']['user']%. But I want to use this in a common flow, so I want to pass in the value of the property name user.
So how would I refer to the custom object property name using a variable. i.e. something like: %input_tsheet_ObjectName% = 'user' .Then %CustomObject['results']['%input_tsheet_ObjectName%']%.

When I try this, I get the error:

